# Converting string to floating point number without bc in bash shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm getting load average in a bash shell script like so

```
load=`echo $(cat /proc/loadavg | awk '{print $1}')`
```

I know piping to bc

```
load=`echo $(cat /proc/loadavg | awk '{print $1}') \> 3 | bc -l`
```

is used in almost all examples of how to cast $load as an int but this box does not have bc installed and I am not allowed to add it.

I tried

```
int=`perl -E "say $load - 0"`
```

I tried

```
int=${load%.*}
```

I tried

```
int=`printf -v int %.0f "$load"`
```

What I want to be able to do is

```
if [ "$int" -gt  3.5 ]; then
```

How do I get that to evaluate as intended?

Comment: Awk prints floating point? Do you mean you want it as an integer?

Comment: If you just want to test if it is greater than 3.5 all you need is awk. `if awk '$1<3.5{exit 1}' /proc/loadavg;then do stuff ;fi`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use awk to produce a success/failure depending on the condition:

```
# exit 0 (success) when load average greater than 3.5, so take the branch
if awk '{ exit !($1 > 3.5) }' /proc/loadavg; then
    # load average was greater than 3.5
fi
```

Unfortunately, since "success" is 0 in the shell, you have to invert the logic of the condition to make awk exit with the required status. Obviously, you can do this in a number of ways, such as changing `>` to `<=`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any external tools (like awk) to read this stuff. Load average from `/proc/loadavg` is always formatted with two decimal places, so you can do this:

```
read load _ < /proc/loadavg

if [ ${load/./} -gt 350 ]; then
  # do something
fi
```

Comment: Why are you using `_`?

Comment: @ULick - the `read` command uses word splitting to separate things into variables, and if there are fewer variables than words, puts the remainder of the line into the last variable. `read load _` reads the first word, and puts the rest of the line into the throw-away variable `$_`.

Comment: @123 - Are we looking for a load average of 3.50, or 35.00? I went with the numbers in the question.

Comment: @ghoti Oh yeah, yeah for some reason i thought it was 35 after reading your answer, no idea why, just ignore my comment :)

Comment: @ghoti The part about the splitting I understood, was just wondering why you used a variable which used by the shell itself (expands to the last argument to the previous command... )

Comment: @ULick - Ah, I see. "Tradition" I guess. I've been doing this way since before bash was born, and afaik `$_` is nothing in POSIX shell. Bash doesn't make this variable read-only, so I'm free to continue to use it as a throw-away. :)